# How to apply to CSS styles to Drupal search form submit button?

Tags: css, drupal, button

I'm absolutely fed up with this. I've been trying for a week trying different code, modifying different values etc. I simply cannot skin my Drupal (6)'s search submit button.

I want to be able to swap out the submit buttons for events like hover, active, and such. One of the biggest issues is that I can't figure out how to change the php code so these CSS styles only are applied to the search submit button, not all the other buttons on the site.

Here is the code I have semi-working at the moment. Right now another issue I face is that, the span tag keeps showing the size is only 45x16px, I've applied width and height properties to be 54x28 but it doesn't change anything.

```
function phptemplate_button($element) {
  // Make sure not to overwrite classes.
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-'. $element['#button_type'] .' '. $element['#attributes']['class'];
  }
  else {
    $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-'. $element['#button_type'];
  }

  // We here wrap the output with a couple span tags
  return '<span class="button"><span><input type="submit" '. (empty($element['#name']) ? '' : 'name="'. $element['#name'] .'" ')  .'id="'. $element['#id'].'" value="'. check_plain($element['#value']) .'" '. drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) ." /></span></span>\n";
}
```

```
span.button  {
    background-image: url('images/go-button.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    width: 53px;
    height: 28px;
}
span.button:hover {
    background-image: url('images/go-button-gifsmooth.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0;
}
span.button:active {
    background-image: url('images/go-button-pressed.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0;
}
span.button span input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to theme the search button for the sites main search page (www.example.com/search), you can use this in *template.php*:

```
function phptemplate_button($element) {
  // Check that the buttons belongs to the site search page
  if ($element['#value'] == 'Search' && $element['#id'] == 'edit-submit') {
    // Make sure not to overwrite classes.
    if (isset($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
      $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-'. $element['#button_type'] .' '. $element['#attributes']['class'];
    }
    else {
      $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-'. $element['#button_type'];
    }

    // We here wrap the output with a couple span tags
    return '<span class="button"><span><input type="submit" '. (empty($element['#name']) ? '' : 'name="'. $element['#name'] .'" ')  .'id="'. $element['#id'].'" value="'. check_plain($element['#value']) .'" '. drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) ." /></span></span><div style='clear:both;'></div>\n";
  }
  else {
    return '<input type="submit" '. (empty($element['#name']) ? '' : 'name="'. $element['#name'] .'" ')  .'id="'. $element['#id'].'" value="'. check_plain($element['#value']) .'" '. drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) ." />\n";
  }
}
```

To alter the button for the "theme search" in header or the "search block", you will have to create a tpl file named either *search-theme-form.tpl.php* or *search-block-form.tpl.php* and place it in your theme directory. Then insert code similar to this:

```
// This is for the theme search... for search block, $search['search_block_form']
<?php print $search['search_theme_form']; ?>
<span class="button"><span><input type='submit' name='submit-form' value='TEST' class='this-submit'/></span></span>
<?php print $search['hidden']; ?>
```

To make the span display as the correct size, I got it working by adding `display: block;` to the style for `span.button`. It may move the button around a little, but with some more CSS you can get it wherever you like.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I've got the buttons now displaying good however I've found an issue with my code... the button only takes you to the link when you click right on top of the text. If you click in the very corner of the button it won't link to it. You can see here (my actual site): http://nside-elite.techiedesign.net/drupal6/user/login?destination=comment/reply/1%23comment-form   could I use some jQuery to set the clickable area for the button in my template.php file? I followed this tutorial here: http://teddy.fr/blog/beautify-your-drupal-forms I don't know how to insert it.

Comment: Please excuse me if it comes across as if I'm just hunting for someone to code for me. I'm new to site design and I'm attempting to learn as much as I can along the way. I recently purchased a Javascript book for beginners and I'm very slowly working my way through that at the moment.

Comment: I don't see it as being a huge major problem now that I got the button background image to actually display. But it just makes the site feel buggy and mediocre. Most people I would assume are going to click the text when they hit the button, but it's just an aggravating issue.

Comment: @Matt I could only see the search in the top right of  the screen and clicking the arrow did nothing. As for using jQuery to enhance your form, yes this is possible. You would need to select the element you wish to add the event handler to (span) but need to be specific. Something along the lines of `$('SELECTOR').click(function() { $('SELECTOR OF FORM ID').submit(); });` will submit the form when the chosen span is clicked. Check out the jQuery docs to learn more: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials. Sorry not more specific, going to bed now, but will take a look in the morning. Good Luck!